# If my external hard drive letter changed, is relinking my dropbox account the right action?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I use dropbox on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. My dropbox account folder is located on an external hard drive. I rebooted the computer and the external hard drive letter changed, which caused the dropbox program not to see the dropbox account folder anymore. Should I relink my account in order to be able to set the correct path?

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just change the drive letter of the drive?

Comment: @Ramhound Taken by a new external hard drive, and I'd prefer the changing its letter. I am surprised that Dropbox won't simply let me change the dropbox account folder location, but maybe relinking is ok (I'm not sure what actions are implied by "restore your dropbox from the web version").

Comment: It means Dropbox will sync your files from your account.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You should now understand that changing the drive letter while you are exited out of Dropbox to match the current Dropbox drive letter is far easier and productive than having Dropbox fully validate all your files on the new drive letter.

Comment: @sunk818 Apparently yes: I'm surprised that there's no way to change Dropbox folder location path in such a situation (instead of having to change the driver letters), but I'll live with that.

Comment: I haven't experimented with the SUBST command in DOS, but it might be worth exploring next time. If your external is assigned a different drive letter, you can use the SUBST to virtually assign a different drive letter. This takes up two drive letters now, but it might be more seamless. You should also take care **NOT** to insert USB flash drives, USB optical drives, etc before booting up which can cause the drive letter change you mentioned. Or you can change your Dropbox drive to A: or B: assuming you will never use a floppy drive on the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, copy everything from the local Dropbox folder on the renamed hard drive to a folder that is not being monitored by Dropbox. Once you've got them someplace safe, re-link Dropbox to the new file location and let it download new copies of everything.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer not to download new copies of everything though, as I have a few TB on my account.

Comment: This won't require any additional space in your Dropbox.

Comment: Sure, but downloading a few TB takes a bit of time: My dropbox account books account contain 3 TB, and the local dropbox folder is 4 TB (which means I have around 1 TB that remains to be synchronized). Also I don't have 3 TB available (which I would need to have if I download new copies of everything in a new location).

Comment: Understood. That is quite a bit of data. Instead of copying all Dropbox files to a local folder, you could download only that 1 TB of unsynced data and move it to a local unsynced folder. That 1 TB of data should include everything that was added/modified after the drive letter was changed. Once that data is secured, you could delete everything and let it resync overnight. In my experience, Dropbox does a good job of backing up and restoring past versions and deleted files.

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect your hard drive that Dropbox is mapped to but leave the other hard drives in to take up the other drive letters. Right click on computer and click "Map network drive". Map the new drive letter that dropbox has adopted with another location. Even duplicate an existing location if you want. You need to let the computer know that that particular drive letter is already taken 'thanks'. Reboot you PC and it can't use that letter for dropbox anymore. If you then plug your hard drive with dropbox on it into your PC it will revert back to the old drive letter. But only if that drive letter is available. If one of your other drives inadvertently adopts the drive letter that you had dropbox on you are in trouble again.